# Split a string with two delimiters into two arrays (explode twice)

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode, delimited

How can I split this string of comma-separated dimensions into two arrays? The string may have many items in it, but it will always have the same two alternating delimiters (exes and commas).

```
$str = "20x9999,24x65,40x5";
```

I need to get two arrays from this string:

```
$array1 = [20, 24, 40];
$array2 = [9999, 65, 5];
```

I've tried many implementations of `preg_split()`, `array_slice()`, and regex. I can't get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string by commas, and then explode each of those values by `x`, inserting the result values from that into the two arrays:

```php
$str = "20x9999,24x65,40x5";

$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach (explode(',', $str) as $key => $xy) {
    list($array1[$key], $array2[$key]) = explode('x', $xy);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), matching against the digits either side of the `x`:

```php
preg_match_all('/(\d+)x(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
$array1 = $matches[1];
$array2 = $matches[2];
```

In both cases the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 40
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9999
    [1] => 65
    [2] => 5
)
```

Note that as of PHP7.1, you can use [array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.destructuring) instead of `list`, so you can just write

```php
[$array1[$key], $array2[$key]] = explode('x', $xy);
```

instead of

```php
list($array1[$key], $array2[$key]) = explode('x', $xy);
```

You can use this to simplify the assignment of the result from `preg_match_all` as well:

```php
[, $array1, $array2] = $matches;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LGok4)

Answer (score 0):

I guess with `preg_split`, we could do so:

```
$str = '20x9999,24x65,40x5';

$array1 = $array2 = array();

foreach (preg_split("/,/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $key => $value) {
    $val = preg_split("/x/", $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    array_push($array1, $val[0]);
    array_push($array2, $val[1]);
}

var_dump($array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "24"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "40"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "9999"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "65"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

Comment: `preg_split` used like that is a lot more expensive than a simple `explode`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the comma-separated, then `x`-delimited sets of data into separate arrays with integer-typed values can be direct achieved by iterating over a comma-exploded array, then making `sscanf()` calls with `%d` placeholders

For other scenarios, use `%f` for floats, `%s` to greedily match consecutive visible characters, and `[^,]`, `[^x]`, etc to match continuous characters not in the list.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sF8no))

```
$one = [];
$two = [];
foreach (explode(',', $str) as $set) {
    sscanf($set, '%dx%d', $one[], $two[]);
}
var_dump($one, $two);
```

Output with `int` typed values:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => int(20)
  [1] => int(24)
  [2] => int(40)
}
array(3) {
  [0] => int(9999)
  [1] => int(65)
  [2] => int(5)
}
```

---

Extending the sample data format to have values which contain delimiting characters, `str_getcsv()` can be rather handy.  Consider the following parse&split approach to preserve the double quoted substring -- which is the natural syntax that a .csv file would use.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t8km6))

```
$str = '"20x9,999",24x65,40x5';
//           ^------------------ don't split on this comma and omit the double quotes
$one = [];
$two = [];
foreach (str_getcsv($str) as $set) {
    [$one[], $two[]] = explode('x', $set);
}
var_dump($one, $two);
```

Choose a combination of these techniques depending on your input and desired output for real world tasks where *nested splitting* is needed.